# What does "Partial Upgrade" when installing OwnCloud client from third party repository?

Tags: partial-upgrade, software-updater, owncloud-client

I have installed owncloud-client from Ubuntu repositories. But it opens a popup on every startup, which informs about a new version. Therefor I decided to get the update from a 3rd party repository and I have added `deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/isv:ownCloud:devel/xUbuntu_12.04/ /` so my sources.

But now my Software Updater opens a dialog titled **Not all updates can be installed** and suggests to make an **Partial Upgrade**. What does that mean, what will the partial upgrade do with my Ubuntu and what consequences do I have to expect?

Comment: I think this is no duplicate because I am not asking for a solution to get rid of the Partial Upgrade dialog. I would like a explanation for its meaning. A Link at least. Thank you.

Comment: I have found a solution to my problem. I had to uninstall the owncloud client provided by Ubuntu.